# ROS parallel computing platforms

Tags: ros, parallel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to use parallel computing in ROS. I found there are so many platforms, like CUDA, OpenCL, OpenML, OpenMPI, OpenACC, etc. Which should I choose? Welcome to talk to me about disadvantges and advantages in ROS and robot applications. Thx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242269/ros-parallel-computing-platforms/) by [taiping.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/26425/taiping.z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS should be compatible with most of those. Which one you choose depends far more on your application and your hardware than on your decision to use ROS

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0